# What motivated CCM's monstrous design?

Tags: algorithm-design, ccm

The formatting function in [Appendix A of NIST-SP-800-38C](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38c.pdf#page=18) is a monster enabling CCM to support variable-length nonce from 7-13 bytes, variable-length encoding of the length of the payload. Also, the tag length is encoded in the formatting function making naive truncating of the MAC tag potentially incompatible with ciphertext instances with specific parameters.

The GCM mode and ChaCha20-Poly1305 are much better - they are similar, both use counter mode, applying MAC over ciphertext, etc.

What motivated IEEE to design CCM like this (NIST imported CCM definition from their draft)?

Comment: Re.:Better... GCM/Cha/poly is streamable. CCM isn't.

Comment: @DannyNiu  You might want to ask the question this way: "What could have motivated IEEE to design CCM...

Comment: With the current wording and it being the IEEE I'm tempted to answer "huffing too many solder flux fumes over the years".

Comment: On the bright side: it does allow you to use CBC-MAC without worrying (overly much) about attacks on it. CMAC requires additional operations. EAX mode does better w.r.t streaming, but it is less efficient as it does use CMAC and some additional memory to store the intermediate authentication. It does have the benefit that you can stream *anything* and *in any order* though, something that is uncommon for other authentication schemes. I do agree that CCM is trying to be too clever and the required bit f***ing is a major headache.

Comment: According to [Rogaway and Wagner](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/ccm.pdf), CCM was designed to avoid the patented OCB in the IEEE 802.11 standard. That standard demanded up to 65536-byte messages and 64-bit tags, so I suppose they figured that specializing the modes like this for each protocol was a good idea..